# Trigger css a:hover inside iframe links

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

So I have an iframe which covers the page, I want to basically make a div cover the whole page by transitioning in on the whole page from left to right when you hover over an `<a>` element. My code so far is this, which doesn't really seem to be doing what I want it to do fully on `<a>` elements which are not even inside the iframe

this is the code I've got so far, I tried doing it through css which sort of works when I try it online but the example on jsfiddle doesn't work that well if at all really.

```
 <a id="example">a link</a>
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%" id="iframe">Your browser doesn't support iFrames.</iframe>
<div class="post-s">
    <a href="#">wolooooloooo</a>>
</div>



.post-s {
    width: 0;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(253,0,0,0.7);
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: 0.7s ease;
  }
a:hover ~ .post-s{
        width: 100%;
    }
```

An example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ejoaxmsw/7/

Comment: There is a reason SO gives you an error when you post a jsfiddle link without code. Try not to hack around that by adding the link into a code block

Comment: Why do you need to use an iframe???

Answer (score 1):

Your link is located under div.post-s, so it is gets lost a:hover when div expanding. You can set link above div

```
#example {
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}
```

or disable pointer events for div

```
.post-s {
pointer-events: none;
}
```